# Gradle Dependency resolution changes from 4.10.3 to 6.1.1

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management

I am currently attempting to upgrade my projects gradle version from 4.10.3 to 6.1.1. The problem I am facing, and am unable to wrap my head around, is a change to the dependency resolution. I do not see any remarks to that in the migration guides.

Specifically what seems to happen, is that some (or all) transitives are getting ignored now. Here is the setup in a simplified form:

I have project **Main** and library **Boot**. **Main** has a dependency on **Boot** which looks like this:

```
implementation group: 'com.example', name: 'boot', version: '1.0'
```

**Boot** has a dependency on the **servlet-api**

```
implementation group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version: '2.5'
```

This is one of plenty examples. In 4.10.3 it is no problem for **Main** to reference the ServletContext. Now it works in my IDE, but the *gradlew compileJava* task fails saying ServletContext is a unknown symbol.

Similar but not exactly the same, I am unable to pass the dependencies from a different sourceSet. Here the second example:
I have project **Service** and library **Commons**. Project **Service** has an additional source set called **api**. Now **Service** contains following dependencies

```
apiImplementation group: "com.example", name: "commons", version: "1.0"

implementaiton sourceSets.api.output
```

With 4.10.3 this works perfectly fine, but with 6.1.1 I am unable to use elements from **commons** in **Service:main**. Here too I have plenty of cases, where it fails.

Usually I would assume that I have forgotten something, and I spent quite some time already scouring the web for clues, but seeing how it works perfectly fine with 4.10.3, but fails with 6.1.1 (no other changes) it must be a change in the dependency resolution, or a change in the syntax. Either way I am unable to find any documentation on the particular subject. My hope is that someone has encountered this issue already, and found a solution to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main module cannot use servlet classes because of [API and implementation separation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation):

> The `api` configuration should be used to declare dependencies which are exported by the library API, whereas the `implementation` configuration should be used to declare dependencies which are internal to the component.

You are using `implementation` configuration and so it's dependecies are not exposed transitively.

Try changing the scope of servlet dependency to `api`, or include servlet dependency into the main module.

Comment: Yes, I've just stumbled across this by accident, as it seems that the maven publish translates implementation into runtime dependencies and api into compile. This was already the case in 4.10.3 but in 6.1.1 it now crashes with the runtime dependencies.